# Calculus application of derivatives

Tags: calculus

Let $g(x) = 2f(x/2) + f(2-x)$ and $f''(x)<0$ for all $x\in (0,2)$. If $g(x)$ increases in $(a,b)$ and decreases in $(c,d)$ find the values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

What I thought was a little graphical approach. I figured it out that if $f''(x)$ is less than zero then $f'(x)$ would be decreasing (not considering the concavity) and the behaviour of $g(x)$ would depend upon $f(x)$. But I couldn't figure out the exact intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
g(x)&=2f\left(\frac x2\right)+f(2-x) \\[2 ex]
g'(x)&=f'\left(\frac x2\right)-f'(2-x) \\[2 ex]
g'\left(\frac 43\right)&=f'\left(\frac 23\right)-f'\left(\frac 23\right) \\[2 ex]
 &= 0
\end{align}$$

so $\dfrac 43$ is a critical point for $g(x)$. (I found that critical point by solving $\dfrac x2=2-x$.) $f''(x)<0$ implies that $f'(x)$ is decreasing, so 
$$u<\frac 23 \implies f'(u)>f'\left(\frac 23\right)$$
$$u>\frac 23 \implies f'(u)<f'\left(\frac 23\right)$$

Thus, for $x<\dfrac 43$, $\dfrac x2<\dfrac 23$ and $2-x>\dfrac 23$, so

$$\begin{align}
g'(x)&=f'\left(\frac x2\right)-f'(2-x) \\[2 ex]
 &> f'\left(\frac 23\right)-f'\left(\frac 23\right) \\[2 ex]
 &=0
\end{align}$$

and similarly $x>\dfrac 43\implies g'(x)<0$. Thus $g(x)$ increases for $x<\dfrac 43$ and increases for $x>\dfrac 43$.

Now we know the behavior of $f$ only for $0<x<2$. The function $g$ is then known only for the intersection of $0<\dfrac x2<2$ and $0<2-x<2$, which is again $0<x<2$. Therefore $g(x)$ increases in $\left(0,\dfrac 43\right)$ and decreases in $\left(\dfrac 43,2\right)$ and we don't know what happens outside the interval $(0,2)$.

> So $a=0,b=c=\dfrac 43,d=2$.

Comment: Why $a=-\infty$ and $d=+\infty$? We know nothing about $f(x)$ if $x\notin (0,2)$.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: You are right, of course. I was so caught up in my editing and caring for a guest in my house that I overlooked this important detail. Thanks for the catch, and +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I figured it out that if $f''(x)$ is less than zero then $f'(x)$ would be decreasing

It's enough. Look:
$$
g'(x) = 2f'(x/2)\cdot \frac12 + f(2-x)\cdot(-1) = f'(x/2) - f(2-x).
$$

**I.** $0< x/2< 2-x$; since $f'(x)$ is decreasing then $g'(x)>0$ and $g(x)$ is increasing.

**II.** $x/2 > 2-x > 0$; since $f'(x)$ is decreasing then $g'(x)<0$ and $g(x)$ is decreasing.

I think you can find $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ now.

Comment: Oh yeah, maybe I need to stress upon my observation . Thanks.